# Error while compiling C program

Tags: compiling, gcc, c

I am new to ubuntu programming. When I Try to compile a C program it shows this kind of error

```
fowler_nordheim_current.c:27:10: fatal error: gsl/gsl_sf.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gsl/gsl_sf.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Please help me out.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install the `libgsl-dev` package:

```
$ apt-file search gsl/gsl_sf.h
libgsl-dev: /usr/include/gsl/gsl_sf.h
```

Comment: Link to [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=gsl_sf.h) (online resource) seems to be better than offline local apt-file which may not be installed.